# Laravel Kill Queue Job

Tags: laravel, amazon-sqs, laravel-queue, laravel-jobs

I am using laravel 5.6 in my project and i needed a queue jobs. I decided to use Amazon Sqs and i connected my application with aws successfully. I create a queue job file with using command:

```
php artisan make:job MakeAmazingJob
```

After that laravel generate a Jobs folder and MakeAmazingJob file. After that with using command:

```
php artisan queue:listen
```

I started my job and it worked succesfully. Then i remove this MakeAmazingJob file and and generate new job file with command:

```
php artisan make:job MakeMoreAmazingJob
```

Then i want to start my new job and and started with command:

```
php artisan queue:liste
```

And in terminal output was:

```
[2020-03-20 12:33:54][382e78ad-ed37-4e08-8f02-a292ebf29cbd] Processing: App\Jobs\MakeAmazingJob
[2020-03-20 12:33:55][382e78ad-ed37-4e08-8f02-a292ebf29cbd] Processing: App\Jobs\MakeMoreAmazingJob
[2020-03-20 12:33:55][382e78ad-ed37-4e08-8f02-a292ebf29cbd] Processed: App\Jobs\MakeMoreAmazingJob
[2020-03-20 12:33:55][382e78ad-ed37-4e08-8f02-a292ebf29cbd] Processing: App\Jobs\MakeAmazingJob
[2020-03-20 12:33:56][382e78ad-ed37-4e08-8f02-a292ebf29cbd] Processing: App\Jobs\MakeAmazingJob
[2020-03-20 12:33:56][1b66ac1a-7071-4878-a565-d4a3895bc243] Processing: App\Jobs\MakeAmazingJob
[2020-03-20 12:33:57][382e78ad-ed37-4e08-8f02-a292ebf29cbd] Processing: App\Jobs\MakeAmazingJob
[2020-03-20 12:33:57][1b66ac1a-7071-4878-a565-d4a3895bc243] Processing: App\Jobs\MakeAmazingJob
[2020-03-20 12:33:58][382e78ad-ed37-4e08-8f02-a292ebf29cbd] Processing: App\Jobs\MakeAmazingJob
[2020-03-20 12:33:58][1b66ac1a-7071-4878-a565-d4a3895bc243] Processing: App\Jobs\MakeAmazingJob
```

Infnitely..

After this output i googled because i excepted and should be laravel should not try process removed job and i found a solution it was a use this command:

```
sudo php artisan queue:restart
```

And i tried and used this command after i started again my jobs, still result is same. Laravel is trying infinitely process to removed job. So, how can kill the removed queue job?

Thanks!

Comment: Try to run `Composer dumpautoload`

Comment: did not work still same infinitely trying process :(

Comment: Then try to deleted the queue related to MakeAmazingJob by running `php artisan queue:flush`

Comment: php artisan queue:flush is using flushing failed jobs but there is no failed job. so that when i tried php artisan queue:flush  i am taking (SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table  amazingproject.failed_jobs' doesn't exist") error